# PDO Exception ZEND Framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, zend-framework2

In my ZF2 project made on ZendServer CE, in file global.php I have this:

```
return array(
  'db'=> array(
      'driver' => 'Pdo',
      'dns' => 'mysql:dbname=test; host=localhost',
      'username' => '***',
      'password' => '***',
      'driver_options' => array(
          PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
      ),
  ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' =>
                'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

but when I try to use the db connection I have this error:

```
Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException
```

File:

```
/var/www/ProvaProgetto/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Connection.php:289
```

Message:

```
Connect Error: could not find driver
```

I tried to check if the pdo extension was enable with 
`php -m | grep -i pdo`
and it returns

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
```

`'/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
    PDO`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does the file `/usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo_mysql.so` exist? If not, is there a similarly named folder in `/usr/lib/php5` instead that contains `pdo_mysql.so`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related with your environment/configuration, not Zend Framework. You have to properly install & configure mysqli/pdo extension(s) first to work with them.

Actually your `php -m | grep -i pdo` command explicitly says the problem; unable to load that extensions.

Check your php.ini, re-install that extensions (if necessary) and/or make sure you enabled them in php.ini, restart your web server.

If i'm not wrong, Zend Server CE should provide a GUI interface to configure/enable/disable extensions. (I never used ZS CE but problem is clear)

Answer (score 2):

'dns' => 'mysql:dbname=test; host=localhost'

Your problem here is 'dns', should be: 'dsn'.

Comment: Exactly! I also face with this error. Source code what we download from Github (`Singleton Application`) have problem at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-arranging your db credentials. Put them in the local.php not global.php (unless the credentials are the same for every environment) and then the array should look like this

### local.php

```
'db'                =>  array
                                (
                                    'adapters'  =>  array
                                                    (
                                                        'test-db'       =>  array
                                                                            (
                                                                                'driver'    =>  'pdo',
                                                                                'dsn'       =>  'mysql:dbname=test; host=localhost',
                                                                                'username'  =>  '**********',
                                                                                'password'  =>  '**********',
                                        'driver_options'    =>  array
                                                    (
                                                            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
                                                                                            ),
                                                    )
                                ),
```

### in your Module.php add

```
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

public function getServiceConfig()
{
return  array
            (
                'factories'     =>  array
                                    (
                                        'Application\Mapper\TestTable'   =>  function($sm)
                                                                                {
                                                                                    $tableGateway   =   $sm->get('TestTableGateway');
                                                                                    $table          =   new TestTable($tableGateway);
                                                                                    return $table;
                                                                                },
                                        'TestTableGateway'               =>  function($sm)
                                                                                {
                                                                                    $dbAdapter          =   $sm->get('test-db');
                                                                                    $resultSetPrototype =   new ResultSet();
                                                                                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Test());
                                                                                    return new TableGateway('actualTableName', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                                                                                },
                                    ),
            );
```

Back to your global change the service_manager array to this:

```
        'service_manager'   =>  array
                                (
                                    'abstract_factories'    =>  array
                                                                (
                                                                    'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterAbstractServiceFactory',
                                                                ),
                                    'factories'             =>  array
                                                                (

                                                                ),
                                ),
```